# New lines (<br>) is automatically getting added in Stylesheets

Tags: vue.js, rollupjs

I am trying to use vue js and roll up for bundling. when am trying to bundle my css and js file , am using vue plugin for rollup `rollup-plugin-vue` and added the config like this ,

`vue({
    compileTemplate: true,
    css:true
 }),`

My problem is when am bundling the file the css files are getting added with new line on every line

```
@charset 'utf-8'
<br>
.class{
<br>
 margin : some value :
 <br>
 }
 ......
```

Help me to get rid of the New line from the css

Edit :

- Created a CSS file
- Added css in App.vue file
- added rollup config to bundle and gzip the js files
- Added vue config like this 
  `vue({
     compileTemplate: true,
     css:true  }),`

Comment: Help us to help you by detailing the steps required to replicate this issue.

Comment: Please show your code so we can better visualize your problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have added the steps that i have tried

Comment: @siva - I wanted the steps to reproduce. Not what you tried. Make sense?

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.querySelector('br').remove();
```

```html
<div>
Lorem Ipsum dolor set amet
</div>
<br>
<div >
Lorem Ipsum dolor set amet
</div><br>
```

You can use the simple script to remove the unnecessary tags.
Limit them to use within the parent element to not affect the other areas.

Comment: He specifically stated that it the issue is during the bundling.  So this method won't work. This will not also gonna work because he stated that the `<br>` tags appeared inside the CSS files and not in the html.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and would also remove the first `<br>` only